# doctrine:build-schema doesn't generate schema properly

Tags: doctrine, schema, symfony-1.4, sfdoctrineguard

I've a previously created DB with sfDoctrineGuard tables and also two more tables: **almunos** and **socios**. I'm trying to run the task

```
symfony doctrine:build-schema
```

and aparently seems to work but surprise only the tables related to sfDoctrineGuard plugin appears and not the others two. Why? Did I miss something? What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Where did you defined the others two tables?

Comment: @j0k do I need to define them? I tough that build-schema takes tables directly from DB and creates the file schema.yml, I'm wrong?

Comment: Oh right, sorry. Yes, you seems to be right, I don't then why it doesn't generate your schema ..

Comment: @j0k ;) don't worry, but something is really wrong here. I run the task `build-schema` and my schema.yml isn't change but I run `build-models` and tables appears > >> tokens /var/www/html/rayundown/lib/model/doctrine/base/BaseSocios.class.php, why?

Comment: What do you have inside your folder `config/doctrine` once the task has run?

Comment: @j0k Ohhhh the schema.yml file with the table definitios, that's my bad, I didn't look there before, forgot complete that Doctrine generates schema inside config/doctrine and not in config/ thanksç

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the task description says:

> The `doctrine:build-schema` task introspects a database to create a
>   schema:
>
> ```
> ./symfony doctrine:build-schema
> ```
>
> The task creates a yml file in `config/doctrine`.

So you have to look inside the folder `config/doctrine` to check the generated `schema.yml`.